# Ajax Content Refresh, only if changed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using an HTML form to input data. I use jQuery to refresh every n seconds a sort of "preview" box in the form, however this should be done only on content change, to avoid unwanted flickery and useless continuous refresh. How can I trigger this with Javascript/jQuery? Test should on content change should be executed on form INPUT fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var isFormChanged = false;

$("input").change(function() {
    isFormChanged = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (isFormChanged) {
        refresh();
        isFormChanged = false;
    }
}, 15000);
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

I have tried your code on a TEXTAREA field and it works only when the focus moves to other elements in the form. Any hint here?

Comment: @Riccardo That's how the `change` event works. You could try using the `keyup` event instead, though that'll lead to some unnecessary refreshes. Another option is to `serialize` your form to a string (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). Every n seconds, serialize the form again and compare it to the previously serialized value. If they differ, then refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
$("#input_id :input").change(function(){
    ajax_refresh_handler(this);
});
```

Comment: The selector `$("#formId :input")` would be better suited to this, I think.

Comment: `$(":input #input_id")` will look for `#input_id` descending from :inputs. It won't match anything :) A space means the *descendant* selector. You want to match input elements descending from a form.